# im trying to make a chat where it shows the username who send the message so people can see who send it

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

im trying to make a chat where people can see the username of the people who send the message but im trying to make a join between my `auth_db` and my `chat_db` but i keep getting the error

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Table 'chat_db.chat_db'
> doesn't exist in C:\xampp\htdocs\SpookyCatChat\chat\page1.php:46 Stack
> trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\SpookyCatChat\chat\page1.php(46):
> mysqli->query('SELECT Message,...') #1 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\SpookyCatChat\chat\page1.php on line 46

Chat DB
[image: Chat_DB]

Auth DB

[image: auth_db]

and this is the code im trying to do the join on

```
<?php 
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['id']) && isset($_SESSION['fname'])) {
    include "../pages/db_conn.php";
    include '../php/User.php';
    $user = getUserById($_SESSION['id'], $conn);
}
?>
<?php

$sName = "localhost";
$uName = "root";
$pass = "";
$db_name = "chat_db";

$conn = new mysqli($sName, $uName, $pass, $db_name);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT Message, auth_db.username
        FROM chat_db
        LEFT JOIN auth_db ON auth_db.username = chat_db.id
        ORDER BY chat_db.id DESC LIMIT 5";

var_dump($sql);

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result && $result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $users['fname'] . ": " . $row['Message'] . "<br><br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "no messages have been exchanged yet";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Looks like the table `chat_db` doesn't exist =). Make sure it it there. Try `SHOW TABLES FROM chat_db`.

Comment: i have used this table before its chat_db->chat-> Message, id

Comment: What is the name of your table? Is it `chat_db` or `chat`? What does `SHOW TABLES FROM chat_db` show?

Comment: how do i use `"SHOW TABLES FROM chat_db"`

Comment: You can run that from you php code, or from phpmyadmin directly

Comment: Why have you got `include "../pages/db_conn.php`...which presumably opens a database connection, and then also some more code to open a database connection directly within your script? Your code seems a little disorganised.

Comment: And you seem to be naming your tables with `_db` at the end. That could be a source of confusion...a table is not a database.

Comment: oow yeah sorry in include it just has my connection to my auth_db and in my code i have the db to chat_db so 2 separate db's

Comment: Really? According to your query, auth_db seems to be a table within the chat database, not a separate database.  Per my last comment, you seem to have some confusing naming conventions.

Comment: oow no auth_db is a seperate db that im trying to join to my chat_db so i can get the usernames out of the auth_db

Comment: `JOIN` joins between _tables_, not databases, unless you prefix the table name with the database name - but you haven't done that. e.g. if your 1st database was called `db1` and your 2nd was called `db2`, and then within each of those you had `table1` and `table2` you could write `SELECT * FROM db1.table1 LEFT JOIN db2.table2 ON...`. But your SQL assumes chat_db and auth_db are tables, not databases, and that they both exist within the same database.

Comment: Did you run the SHOW TABLES command yet? What was the result?

Comment: the only thing it showed was the table Chat and that is it

Comment: Well then, that's all you have in that database. So `FROM chat_db LEFT JOIN auth_db` won't work because there are no tables with those names within the `chat_db` database. Do you understand the difference between a table and a database? And do you understand what I wrote above, that JOIN works on tables, not databases?

Comment: yes a table is what i make inside of a database where i store all the information

Comment: What about `SHOW TABLES FROM auth_db`...what does that give you?

Comment: it gives me the table users what is the table inside that db

Comment: Ok. So probably your query should be `SELECT Message, auth_db.username FROM chat_db.chat c LEFT JOIN auth_db.users u ON u.username = c.id ORDER BY u.id DESC LIMIT 5` . You forgot to name the tables in your query, you only named the databases. (I've also added the use of aliases to make it shorter to reference the tables in other parts of the query).

Comment: Although looking at the data, the contents of the username field is all text, and the contexts of `id` in the chat table is all numbers, so they will never match

Comment: You don't appear to have any fields in `chat` whose values matches any fields in `users`. The `user` field in `chat` is empty though...is that supposed to contain a username?

Comment: yeah but i wanted to match the id of the user in chat_db with the user id in my other database

Comment: Ok. Well for that, first you have to put the ID of the user in the chat table. You don't seem to have done that.

Comment: how would i do that ?

Comment: is it maybe better to just restart?

Comment: `how would i do that`...well you can edit them into the existing rows via phpMyAdmin, just to fix those items. But if you're talking about when you create those chat values...well the code which inserts the chat data into the database must also insert the ID of the user who the chat data belongs to. (P.S. Surely though you'll need _two_ user fields in there...one for who the message is from, and another for who it's been sent to?).

Comment: I do think maybe you need to go back and rethink your database design a bit. I'd also be very surprised if you really need 2 separate databases, that seems to be overcomplicated for no reason. You could have the "users" and "chat" tables all within the chat_db database. And also in PHP, if both databases are on the same server you don't need to make two separate connections to them, as long as the mysql username you use can access both the databases (which "root" can...although you must not use that superuser account in a live system from PHP, that's a security risk).

Comment: what would be a better way to go about this?

Comment: Well...I think my last two comments just described a better way, or at least the start of one. At the very least I think I've prompted some questions you need to ask yourself about how you want it to work. Obviously I don't know all your exact requirements, so I can't advise on a full database design (nor is that a service that Stackoverflow really provides, anyway...it tends to be too much work for a single question. Instead we focus on providing answers to questions about specific bugs or issues).

Comment: oke i understand well i put the table in 1 db now and now im at the point where it shows the usernames name so atleast chat is working now only have to figure out how to see the usernames out of the other table